# Create a file with string on s3 using aws command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to create a file with a string on s3 using the aws command, i cannot find such a thing in aws cli documentation, has anyone came across such thing ?

Comment: what do you mean by a file with a string?

Comment: The best way is to create a local file, then copy it to Amazon S3. Would this be suitable for your situation?

Answer (score 14):

The `aws s3 cp` command can take input from stdin:

```
echo Hello | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/foo.txt
```

It can also send content to stdout:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/foo.txt -
```

See:

- [AWS Command line: S3 content from stdin or to stdout | Loige](https://loige.co/aws-command-line-s3-content-from-stdin-or-to-stdout/)
- Bottom of this page: [`cp` — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)